# Should I use local videos or youtube videos

Tags: ios

I'm developing an iOS app that is going to use plenty of videos. The app in summary is a quiz app, where after each question it shows your a video relevant to that question.
my question is, should I use local videos or just referencing youtube links to show the videos? keep in mind that all of the videos that I am going to show are youtube videos that I have already downloaded and added to the app bundle.
what are the benefits and downfalls of each? in terms of app development and user interaction?

Comment: This question seems better suited for [ux.stackexchange.com](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the things that you need to consider are

1. Size of the app with all videos inside. If you add everything in the
   bundle than the size of the application will be big and some people
   will reject to download it especially if they are not in wifi
   network
2. Do you need these videos if you don't have a network? If yes, you
   have two options, the first one to add everything in the bundle and the second one to download them inside the app when the app starts.
3. What about the speed? Is it okay to wait for the stream or you need instant play?

I think these are the 3 main points for this. (Size, Offline, Speed)

If you have everything in the bundle Offline support and speed of playing will be okay. But for sure you can have a problem with the size. If everything is in youtube the size will be fine but then you will have problems with the speed and the offline mode.

Comment: thanks, I'll take everything into consideration. I'm still a beginner in iOS development!